# Problems adding new sliders with javascript in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm trying to add a new slider to a site (and 3º one... I already have 2), but when I try to add another, it doesn't work. I'm using javascript, but I don't know how to put the numbers (1,0) (1,1) etc. I have tried several options, but I can't get the correct one.

**HTML:**

1º slider

```
<div class="slideshow-container" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">
<div class="mySlides1">
<div class="numbertext">1/11</div>
<img src="IMG/Femeni-no/femenino-00.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text-femenino">Femeni-NO</div>
</div>
```

2º slider

```
<div class="slideshow-container" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">
<div class="mySlides2">
<div class="numbertext">1/6</div>
<img src="IMG/Parasito/01.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text-parasito">Parásito</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var slideIndex = [1,1];
/* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"] 
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1} 
if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block"; 
}// JavaScript Document
```

//disclaimer// I'm a begginer in coding and web design, willing to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be aware of that 
`var slideIndex = [1,1];` !
in a glance i think array size limit could cause trouble.